# How to find a UI element in a web page built on slds (Salesforce)?

Tags: html, dom

Haven't done web programming in a while - nor do I think ever interacted with a site built on Salesforce.  The site is a California state site that's part of my work but not publicly available.

As part of web automation want to start by clicking on the button under a pencil icon which will transition the page to edit mode.

I've experimented with some javascript expressions to find the button that I want. The first couple didn't work.  This one does - sort of:

let test1 = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-button")

the problem is that it returns an array of 58 items.

The object I want to find in its raw form is as follows:

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-bare" title="Edit" type="button" value="Status"><lightning-primitive-icon><svg class="slds-button__icon" focusable="false" data-key="edit" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><g><g><path d="M9.5 33.4l8.9 8.9c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0L42 20c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-8.8-8.8c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0L9.5 32.1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.3zM36.1 5.7c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l8.8 8.8c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l2.5-2.5c1.6-1.5 1.6-3.9 0-5.5l-4.7-4.7c-1.6-1.6-4.1-1.6-5.7 0l-2.3 2.5zM2.1 48.2c-.2 1 .7 1.9 1.7 1.7l10.9-2.6c.4-.1.7-.3.9-.5l.2-.2c.2-.2.3-.9-.1-1.3l-9-9c-.4-.4-1.1-.3-1.3-.1l-.2.2c-.3.3-.4.6-.5.9L2.1 48.2z"></path></g></g></svg></lightning-primitive-icon><span class="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you stated you are selecting the `className` from webpage, so you will always get list of elements which uses same `css` class. So in your case I am assuming you want to use `className` and get the result, so here is the snippet which will give you result which you want to achieve:

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-button");
var searchText = "Status"; // your button element value attribute text
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  if (btn[i].value == searchText) {
    found = btn[i];
    break;
  }
}

//console.log("Button Element: ", found);
```

Here is sample code example which has 3 buttons with same `CSS` class but different text in `value` attribute:

```js
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-button");
var searchText = "Status"; // your button element value attribute text
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  if (btn[i].value == searchText) {
    found = btn[i];
    break;
  }
}
console.log("Button Element: ", found);
```

```html
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-bare" title="Edit" type="button" value="Status"><lightning-primitive-icon><svg class="slds-button__icon" focusable="false" data-key="edit" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><g><g><path d="M9.5 33.4l8.9 8.9c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0L42 20c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-8.8-8.8c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0L9.5 32.1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.3zM36.1 5.7c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l8.8 8.8c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l2.5-2.5c1.6-1.5 1.6-3.9 0-5.5l-4.7-4.7c-1.6-1.6-4.1-1.6-5.7 0l-2.3 2.5zM2.1 48.2c-.2 1 .7 1.9 1.7 1.7l10.9-2.6c.4-.1.7-.3.9-.5l.2-.2c.2-.2.3-.9-.1-1.3l-9-9c-.4-.4-1.1-.3-1.3-.1l-.2.2c-.3.3-.4.6-.5.9L2.1 48.2z"></path></g></g></svg></lightning-primitive-icon><span class="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span></button>

<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-bare" title="Edit" type="button" value="Status_other"><lightning-primitive-icon><svg class="slds-button__icon" focusable="false" data-key="edit" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><g><g><path d="M9.5 33.4l8.9 8.9c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0L42 20c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-8.8-8.8c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0L9.5 32.1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.3zM36.1 5.7c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l8.8 8.8c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l2.5-2.5c1.6-1.5 1.6-3.9 0-5.5l-4.7-4.7c-1.6-1.6-4.1-1.6-5.7 0l-2.3 2.5zM2.1 48.2c-.2 1 .7 1.9 1.7 1.7l10.9-2.6c.4-.1.7-.3.9-.5l.2-.2c.2-.2.3-.9-.1-1.3l-9-9c-.4-.4-1.1-.3-1.3-.1l-.2.2c-.3.3-.4.6-.5.9L2.1 48.2z"></path></g></g></svg></lightning-primitive-icon><span class="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span></button>

<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-bare" title="Edit" type="button" value="Status_other_button"><lightning-primitive-icon><svg class="slds-button__icon" focusable="false" data-key="edit" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 52 52"><g><g><path d="M9.5 33.4l8.9 8.9c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0L42 20c.4-.4.4-1 0-1.4l-8.8-8.8c-.4-.4-1-.4-1.4 0L9.5 32.1c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.3zM36.1 5.7c-.4.4-.4 1 0 1.4l8.8 8.8c.4.4 1 .4 1.4 0l2.5-2.5c1.6-1.5 1.6-3.9 0-5.5l-4.7-4.7c-1.6-1.6-4.1-1.6-5.7 0l-2.3 2.5zM2.1 48.2c-.2 1 .7 1.9 1.7 1.7l10.9-2.6c.4-.1.7-.3.9-.5l.2-.2c.2-.2.3-.9-.1-1.3l-9-9c-.4-.4-1.1-.3-1.3-.1l-.2.2c-.3.3-.4.6-.5.9L2.1 48.2z"></path></g></g></svg></lightning-primitive-icon><span class="slds-assistive-text">Edit</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.  That looked promising but the code doesn't find any of the 55 buttons where value == "Status"  So I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Ideally it should work, will update the code with sample snippet demo, please have a look and see if you are doing the same.

Comment: I agree that your code should work with the snippet demo you provide.  My problem is in interacting with the website I need to work with and it's possible there are things going on 'around' (above) this code that affect the behavior I'm seeing.  I need to search on this but one possibility that occurred to me is: I wonder if when someone builds a Salesforce site it's possible to restrict programmatic interaction?  I need to research further what's going but your code has been helpful in pushing me forward a not unuseful distance even if I'm not still fully there.